# Get Total Average of Column in One Row SQL

Tags: sql, average, sql-server-2014

I am an intern at an insurance company and was given an assignment to calculate the average value of premiums for x amount of customers.

I am using SQL Server 2014!!

Here below is my query:

```
SELECT  

    Customer.custno 
    , Customer.custid 
    , (Customer.firstname + ' ' + Customer.lastname) AS Client 
    , BasicPolInfo.enteredDate
    , BasicPolInfo.changedDate
    , BasicPolInfo.fulltermpremium AS Premium
    , AVG(BasicPolInfo.fulltermpremium) over(ORDER BY Customer.custno 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS 'Total Premium'

FROM 
    
    Customer INNER JOIN
    BasicPolInfo ON Customer.CustId = BasicPolInfo.CustId INNER JOIN
    Transaction ON BasicPolInfo.PolId = Transaction.PolId INNER JOIN
    GeneralLedgerBranch ON Customer.GLBrnchCode = GeneralLedgerBranch.GLBrnchCode INNER JOIN
    GeneralLedgerDepartment ON Customer.GLDeptCode = GeneralLedgerDepartment.GLDeptCode INNER JOIN
    GeneralLedgerDivision ON Customer.GLDivCode = GeneralLedgerDivision.GLDivCode INNER JOIN
    Employee ON BasicPolInfo.ExecCode = Employee.EmpCode

WHERE   

    Customer.Active = 'Y'  
    AND BasicPolInfo.poltypelob = 'Homeowners'
    AND BasicPolInfo.status <> 'D'
    AND BasicPolInfo.fulltermpremium > '0.00'
    AND BasicPolInfo.polexpdate >= GetDate()


GROUP BY 
    
Customer.custno 
    , Customer.custid
    , Customer.firstname 
    , Customer.lastname 
    , BasicPolInfo.ChangedDate
    , BasicPolInfo.entereddate
    , Employee.firstname
    , Employee.lastname
    , Customer.enteredDate
    , basicpolinfo.fulltermpremium

ORDER BY 

    Customer.enteredDate ASC
```

So my table looks like this:

> Custno | CustID | Client | EnteredDate | ChangedDate | Premium | TotalPremium
>
> xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxxx | 1350.38 | 1350.38
>
> xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxxx | 3517.00 | 2433.69
>
> xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxxx | 2094.00 | 2320.46
>
> xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxxx | 1811.00 | 2193.09

etc.

So what my boss wants is only one column of the average. For example, if this only had 4 customers, then it would ONLY show 2193.09 (inclusive of all the previous calculations to get there) and not show thousands of rows.

> Total Premium
>
> 2193.09

Please comment if you have any questions. I tried my best honestly to explain it the best way I can...

We are trying to graphically represent only the 1 total premium average.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: So the last `custno` TotalPremium(ie 2193.09) is what you need. Since it calculated from the first `custno`

Comment: 2193.09 isn't the average of those 4... so what is it you're after? or is your example flawed? 2074.405 is... the average of those 4...

Comment: Yes it is. I add 1350.38 + 3517.00 + 2094.00 + 1811.00 = 2193.09

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly, you just need to wrap your entire query in:

```
SELECT AVG(Premium)
FROM 
( 

  <your query>

) as MyQuery
```

Comment: replace sum with Avg and you might have it.

Comment: I changed my query to what you said, but rather than the final results of my original query (1558.1748), I got 1581.139. (value is off by 23).

Comment: where'd you get your number from? one might have rounding errors or not be accounting for trailing digits.

Comment: I only gave the first 4 rows of my actual query. In total, I have 7759 rows. Therefore 7759 customers and 7759 premiums being averaged.

Comment: However you are manually arriving at the calculation probably has rounding errors.

Comment: I think what is needed is `SELECT AVG(Premium)` on the first line here. `TotalPremium` looks like a running average, so in theory the last row would be the final average. So you're really averaging the running average. He could probably just get rid of the `TotalPremium` column.

Answer (score 0):

Different way of doing the same thing...

```
With CTE AS (SELECT  
    Customer.custno 
    , Customer.custid 
    , (Customer.firstname + ' ' + Customer.lastname) AS Client 
    , BasicPolInfo.enteredDate
    , BasicPolInfo.changedDate
    , BasicPolInfo.fulltermpremium AS Premium
    , AVG(BasicPolInfo.fulltermpremium) over(ORDER BY Customer.custno 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS 'Total Premium'

FROM 

    Customer INNER JOIN
    BasicPolInfo ON Customer.CustId = BasicPolInfo.CustId INNER JOIN
    Transaction ON BasicPolInfo.PolId = Transaction.PolId INNER JOIN
    GeneralLedgerBranch ON Customer.GLBrnchCode = GeneralLedgerBranch.GLBrnchCode INNER JOIN
    GeneralLedgerDepartment ON Customer.GLDeptCode = GeneralLedgerDepartment.GLDeptCode INNER JOIN
    GeneralLedgerDivision ON Customer.GLDivCode = GeneralLedgerDivision.GLDivCode INNER JOIN
    Employee ON BasicPolInfo.ExecCode = Employee.EmpCode

WHERE   

    Customer.Active = 'Y'  
    AND BasicPolInfo.poltypelob = 'Homeowners'
    AND BasicPolInfo.status <> 'D'
    AND BasicPolInfo.fulltermpremium > '0.00'
    AND BasicPolInfo.polexpdate >= GetDate()


GROUP BY 

Customer.custno 
    , Customer.custid
    , Customer.firstname 
    , Customer.lastname 
    , BasicPolInfo.ChangedDate
    , BasicPolInfo.entereddate
    , Employee.firstname
    , Employee.lastname
    , Customer.enteredDate
    , basicpolinfo.fulltermpremium

ORDER BY 

    Customer.enteredDate ASC)

SELECT AVG(fulltermpremium) from cte
```